# How can they find my subdomains from ssl certificates?

Tags: subdomain

I did a wildcard subdomain like: *.sub.example.com
And I created an ssl certificate (non wildcard certificate) with certbot: site.sub.example.com.

Subdomain checker sites found my subdomains almost immediately. I'm trying to understand and learn how are they doing it if they didn't know my site.sub.example.com subdomain address. How can I hide a subdomain in the future If I have to? I use debian, apache webserver and certbot.

Comment: what makes you think they use your ssl certificate to find your subdomain? either your certificate has SAN (Subject Alternative Name) which indeed allows to see the other subdomains it has been generated for, or (more probably?) someone used a DNS client to find it. (try Googling "find subdomains for a domain", you'll find a lot ot ways to dos so)

Comment: I thought they get the ssl certificate, because they write out my ssl certificate expiration date. You can test it too with your domain name: "subdomainfinder.io". They get the subdomain name in 30 minutes, and is strange. I started thinking about security leak, because you can't get the exact subdomain name from wildcard record.

Comment: I share you astonishement. I just tested with a domain of mine, which has no declared subdomains but a wildcard with a CNAME: `* IN CNAME @.` and certificates issued by LetsEncrypt for each subdomain, and yet sbdomainefinder.io was able to find every subdomains I use... I suspect that they ahve a way of querying DNS caches and not only DNS declarations.

Comment: Thanks, I think I found the solution. Create a wildcard domain with a wildcard ssl certificate and they can't track the subdomain.